# Creating a Numpy matrix that results from subtracting from within a 3D matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following 3D Numpy matrix:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.random([4, 3, 4])

array([[[0.86061437, 0.28274671, 0.08120691, 0.07529454],
        [0.93281252, 0.28959613, 0.89955385, 0.23104958],
        [0.70399225, 0.78649787, 0.65668005, 0.1078731 ]],

       [[0.2604536 , 0.74093858, 0.71550647, 0.07096532],
        [0.49281007, 0.04934752, 0.2316176 , 0.8452892 ],
        [0.5559128 , 0.89977194, 0.60539768, 0.88640264]],

       [[0.21532865, 0.02557637, 0.70641993, 0.86614863],
        [0.26946359, 0.00956061, 0.91330073, 0.0074185 ],
        [0.79044557, 0.50265835, 0.70721046, 0.69482905]],

       [[0.15602922, 0.65337023, 0.44756636, 0.97871331],
        [0.60633134, 0.93488194, 0.53871744, 0.48607869],
        [0.39678678, 0.02369235, 0.42945214, 0.48460456]]])
```

If we splice `arr` with `v = arr[:,0,0]`, we get:

```
array([0.86061437, 0.26045360, 0.21532865, 0.15602922])
```

I would like to create a matrix like the one in yellow below that results from **subtracting** each element from every other element:

[image]

My initial thought was to take `arr[:,0,0]` and the transpose `arr[:,0,0].T`, then try to do the subtraction this way.  But, not sure how to do it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: sorry I'm confused - does the big array have anything to do with the question or are you just asking about how to work with the vector? and yeah something like `v.reshape(-1, 1) - v` should work

Comment: Yes, `arr` is central to the question.

Comment: but how? it seems like you're only working with the 0th slice along the 2nd and 3rd dimensions. can you explain more clearly what you want the result to look like, what you've tried, and where you're stuck?

Comment: `v.reshape(-1, 1) - v` works perfectly.  Thank you.  My goal is to create this type of matrix for each of `A[:, x, y]` where x is 0 to 2 and y is 0 to 4.  I think a for loop might be appropriate.  Although, there may be a better way.

Comment: my hint and @marat's answer both make use of numpy's [*broadcasting*](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) rules - give these docs a good read - they're super helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close:

```
arr.T[..., None, :] - arr.T[..., None]
```

Comment: @Murat, Michael Delgado -- `arr.T[..., None, :] - arr.T[..., None]` seems to result in a matrix that is a *different size* than the original `arr`.  Is it possible to get a matrix of differences that is the same size as the original `arr`?  Thanks!

Comment: @equanimity that's what I was trying to say in that separate question. From this original question, it seems to be intentional - for each 4 values in the original array the expected result contains 4x4=16 values. Can you clarify the intent in of this question then?

Comment: My goal is to take the average of axis 0 in `arr`, but only if the differences in axis 0 are within a certain limit (e.g. if the differences are less than 2, then average those values and throw away the other values).  So, I was trying to get that "differences" matrix that you helped me with.  Then, using that matrix, I was trying to apply some sort of boolean mask and use the mask to take the averages of axis 0.  I might be complicating things.  I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: @equanimity can you clarify what is meant by "the difference"?

Comment: By "the difference", I was referring to the subtraction of the elements.  It's what `arr.T[..., None, :] - arr.T[..., None]` does.

Comment: @equanimity Say, axis 0 contains elements: 1, 2, 4, 6. What is expected to be the average?

Comment: If axis 0 of the "differences" matrix **that results from `arr`** contains elements 1, 2, 4, 6, and the "limit" is, say, >=3, then the average would be 1.5 (because we discard 4 and 6) and average the remaining 1 and 2.

Comment: @equanimity why dowe discard 1 and 2 and not 4 and 6?

Comment: let's assume the values in the original `arr` matrix are measurements of some sort.  Some of the measurements might be erroneous.  So, the idea was to 1) create a new identity matrix (let's call it `B`) containing the subtraction of values in axis 0 of `arr`.  Then, we apply a filter (let's call that `limit`) to `B` and filter out anything greater than the value of `filter`.  If `limit` is, say, >= 3, then we filter out 4 and 6 from the`B` matrix and take the average of the remaining values in axis 0.

Comment: @equanimity this approach does not make sense, and even the described logic does not clearly favor eliminating 4 and 6 vs 1 and 2.

Comment: @equanimity for practical purposes, I'd just use median as it's a lot less sensitive to outliers (well, if the distribution of measurements allows - which is very likely)